# Uncountable locally finite group contains a countably infinite normal subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is it true that every uncountable locally finite group contains a countably infinite normal subgroup? If not, is there a counter example of an uncountable locally finite group that has no countably infinite normal subgroup?

Comment: There exists a profusion of simple uncountable groups. SO(3) is such a group.

Comment: Thank you @YCor! I didn't know that $SO(3)$ is locally finite.

Comment: I mean you're being very polite, but it's clear that $SO(3)$ is not locally finite, right? For instance, there are elements of infinite order (irrational rotations). Maybe YCor just didn't notice this part of your assumption.

Comment: @bof Yes that's a counterexample, you could answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "locally finite" assumption. Still there are many locally finite ones. For instance, the group of even finitely supported permutations of a set of infinite cardinal $\alpha$ is a simple, locally finite group of cardinal $\alpha$ for every $\alpha$. (Its simplicity is an immediate consequence of those $A_n$ being simple for large $n$.) [Edit: this standard example was proposed in other comments.]

Comment: @bof Everything is difficult before it is dumb!